# Encrypting and Verifying a Hashed Password with Salt using Pbkdf2 Encryption

Tags: c#, encoding, asp.net-core, cryptography, passwords

I am using the following code to created a hashed password and salt:

```
// generate a 128-bit salt using a secure PRNG
byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
{
    rng.GetBytes(salt);
}

// derive a 256-bit subkey (use HMACSHA1 with 10,000 iterations)
string hashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
    password: password,
    salt: salt,
    prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
    iterationCount: 10000,
    numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
```

I am storing the HashedPassword and Salt in the database.

**Now I want to verify the password on User Login:**

```
public bool VerifyPassword(string userEnteredPassword, string dbPasswordHash, string dbPasswordSalt)
{
    string hashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: userEnteredPassword,
        salt: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dbPasswordSalt),
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));

    return dbPasswordHash == hashedPassword;
}
```

This is not working, I am getting a completely different hashed password than the one stored in the database. From what I understand you are supposed to prepend the salt to the password that the user enters when logging in and then run the same Hash Password function. Wouldn't the above be the equivalent to that?

Comment: It looks right; I would make sure your salts are actually the same between the two

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was thinking something might be going on with the byte[] to string and string to byte[] conversions.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET ahh I think I see what is going on, but don't know how to fix it. I am storing the salt into a nvarchar field in the database using Encoding.ASCII.GetString(salt). When I look at what is being stored in the database there is a missing character [] symbol being stored as if one of the characters couldn't be stored.

Comment: Your salt is a random buffer not a string so `string dbPasswordSalt` is not what you want.  Store it as varbinary in the DB and read it back into a `byte[]` for `salt:`

Comment: @AlexK. What if I use Convert.ToBase64String(salt) when saving to the database then Convert.FromBase64String(dbSalt) when retrieving from the database. It looks like it is working. Should I really use varbinary as yhe db field type? Previously I was trying to store it in the database using: Encoding.ASCII.GetString(salt).

Comment: Well if you use varbinary you don't need the base64 round trip and the storage size is smaller.  Neither factor likely matters that much so its up to you.

Comment: A small suggestion: use UTF-8 for the password and other parameters to be hashed. They are consistent on Android, BSDs, Unix, Linux, iOS, OS X and Windows. Things :just work". ASCII, UTF-16 and UTF-32 will make you perform conversions on some of the platforms some of the time.

Comment: @jww What is Convert.ToBase64String doing compared to all of the formats you mentioned? It is working for me.

Comment: ASCII / UTF-8 and such are used to transform text to binary (bytes to be precise) so the text can be used as bytes - as required, for instance, by PBKDF2. Base64, on the other hand, is used to transform binary to text. You cannot use ASCII *decoding* instead of base 64 *encoding* to convert bytes to text (as you are doing in the question) because not all bytes are valid ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

As Maarten Bodewes mentioned, ASCII was the problem. The code below returns true. All I changed was `salt: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dbPasswordSalt),` to `salt: System.Convert.FromBase64String(dbPasswordSalt),`

```
public bool VerifyPassword(string userEnteredPassword, string dbPasswordHash, string dbPasswordSalt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dbPasswordSalt.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(dbPasswordHash.ToString());

        string hashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: userEnteredPassword,
            salt: System.Convert.FromBase64String(dbPasswordSalt),///Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dbPasswordSalt),
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
        Console.WriteLine(hashedPassword.ToString());
        return dbPasswordHash == hashedPassword;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the password

Create a salt with the bellow code:

```
    byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
```

Then create a hashed password using that salt.

```
string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: password,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
```

Save the salt that used in somewhere (ex: database) 
Save the hashed password for that user.

2. Validate the password

   - Retrieve the salt and hashed password for that user.
   - Create a hashed password using the retrieved salt and the user entered password.
   - Check newly hashed password and stored password is the same.